# Unlock android bootloader without OEM unlock on

Tags: android, adb, bootloader, fastboot

I have a Google Pixel 4XL that I want to have the bootloader unlocked on to install stuff on it. The OEM Unlocking option is greyed out in the system developer options menu, but I would like to know if there is a way to manually unlock the bootloader with adb and fastboot. When I boot the phone into fastboot mode, I see that the bootloader is locked.

Comment: Usually Google devices should be bootloader unlockable. Is this a plain Google phone or is it branded by a mobile network operator? Or is some mobile device management software installed (from a company for remote administration)? BTW: Stackoverflow is for programming questions not for Android hacking. https://android.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask (unfortunately Android Stackexchange is not in the list of migration targets - @community does somebody know why?) so I can't move your question there..

Comment: @Robert A) Thanks for telling me about android.stackexchange.com and B) I'm not sure what it is. I bought it off of Ebay and it was described as "Unlocked". It doesn't show any carrier logos on boot up like some androids.

Comment: Have you tried to simply unlock it in flashboot state? May be the bootloader was unlocked and then relocked. I am not sure if afterwards OEM unlock in settings is required again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootloader wont unlock on Google Pixel 2 (G011A)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233310/bootloader-wont-unlock-on-google-pixel-2-g011a)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `fastboot oem unlock-go` or `fastboot flashing unlock` to did this. When I tried flashing unlock, it is works